# Paypal Recurring Subscription cart auto cancellation happening always

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

Hi I am using paypal recurring subscription for my one opencart website

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypal">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
   <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@eyelook.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="1 • DAY ACUVUE DEFINE with Lacreon">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1DAY-DEFINE-30">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="50.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="weight_1" value="50">
   <input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="RIGHT EYE">
   <input type="hidden" name="os0_1" value=" ">
   <input type="hidden" name="on1_1" value="Colour">
   <input type="hidden" name="os1_1" value="Accent Style BLACK">
   <input type="hidden" name="on2_1" value="Base Curve">
   <input type="hidden" name="os2_1" value="8.5">
   <input type="hidden" name="on3_1" value="Power">
   <input type="hidden" name="os3_1" value="-0.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="on4_1" value="Diameter">
   <input type="hidden" name="os4_1" value="14.2">
   <input type="hidden" name="on5_1" value="Subscription">
   <input type="hidden" name="os5_1" value="Every 2 Months">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Shipping, Handling, Discounts &amp; Taxes">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="3.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="weight_2" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="SGD">
   <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Test Niyaz">
   <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Hussain">
   <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="       sdsdsds">
   <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="city" value="dsdsd">
   <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="121323">
   <input type="hidden" name="country" value="NE">
   <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="niyak2@gmail.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="12898 - Test Niyaz Hussain">
   <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="en">
   <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
   <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://eyelookgood.com/index.php?route=checkout/success">
   <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://eyelookgood.com/index.php?route=payment/pp_standard/callback">
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://eyelookgood.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout">
   <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="12898">
   <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="OpenCart_2.0_WPS">
   <input type="button" onclick="checkSubscription();" value="Confirm Order" class="btn btn-primary">
 </form>
```

I have contacted the paypal guys. They said it's a setting issue. May I know what is the error in the above code? Please help me out for this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You must use in your html form parameters "p3" and "t3".**

> **p3**:  Specify an integer value in the allowable range for the units of duration that you specify with t3.
>   **t3**: Regular subscription units of duration.
>
> **Allowable values are:**
> **D** – for days; allowable range for **p3** is 1 to 90
> **W** – for weeks; allowable range for **p3** is 1 to 52
> **M** – for months; allowable range for **p3** is 1 to 24
> **Y** – for years; allowable range for **p3** is 1 to 5
>
> **Also the cmd parameter must be _xclick-subscriptions instead _cart**

**Follow this example:**

```
<form method="post" name="formName" id="submitThisForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@papypamail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Membership" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="SECURITYCODE" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="page going after payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="ITEM DESCRIPTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_listener_file.php" />
```

> The allowable range for parameter "p3" is 1 to 24.

**In your case must set**

```
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
```

**AND**

```
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is appear you are not created a subscription button because the value="_s-xclick" is missing. For subscription button you shopuld specified below variable in your button code ;

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
```

You can have a reference [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU).